# type conversion for struct of array from c++ to c

Tags: c++, struct, type-conversion

I have two libraries, from C++ and C, respectively:

lib A in C++:

```
typedef struct { 
   char val[4096]; 
} AString;
```

lib B in C:

```
typedef struct STRING_TYPE{
   unsigned char *u1_list;
   signed int    i4_length;
} BString;
```

If I cannot touch lib A & B code, i.e., cannot add a cast operator in AString class. How to convert from AString to BString?

**EDIT 1**: no separate function defined:

```
AString as=XXX; // given variable 'as' to convert, 
unsigned char p[4096]; 
size_t const N = std::min(strlen(as.val), 4096); 
BString bs = { p, N }; 
std::copy( static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[0]), static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[N]), bs.u1_list ); 
// or use memcpy like: 
memcpy (bs.u1_list, as.val, N+1);
// then follows the part to use converted variable bs;
func(bs);
```

but the code is not module structured.

or else:

**EDIT 2**: which is essentially EDIT_1, define a function,

```
void convert (AString& as, BString& bs)
{
    size_t const N = std::min(strlen(as.val), 4096);
    std::copy( static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[0]), static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[N]), bs.u1_list ); 
    // or use memcpy like: 
    memcpy (bs.u1_list, as.val, N+1);  
    bs.i4_length = N;            
}
```

but before call this function, the user has to define an array, like

```
AString as=XXX; // given variable 'as' to convert, 
unsigned char p[4096]; 
BString bs;
bs.u1_list = p; 
convert(as, bs);
// then follows the part to use converted variable bs;
func(bs);
```

Both are quite awkward.

Isn't there any self-contained, separate-function way to do this?

Comment: Why is this tagged "C++"  if you're using `typedef struct`?

Comment: @marinara: Not really. C++ is as much about idioms and conventions as it is about syntax, _especially_ when dealing with code that compiles as either C++ or C. Really, though, Kerrek should have asked "why are you using `typedef struct` in C++?"

Comment: @pepero: I don't understand the relevance of C vs C++ here.

Comment: @Tomalak, well, it just happens to be my case. no relevance to the key question here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
BString convert(AString const& as)
{
   size_t const N = std::min(strlen(as.val), 4096);

   BString bs = { new unsigned char[N], N };
   std::copy(
      static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[0]),
      static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[N]),
      bs.u1_list
   );

   return bs;
}
```

Be sure to document the fact that this memory can now be leaked. Both types seem like strange things to pass around in C++, to be honest; what's wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: strlen is unsafe here, use strnlen (you know the max is 4096)

Comment: @pepero: You must remember to `delete` the buffer that `u1_list` points to when you're done with it.

Comment: @Yuval: My answer relates to standard C++, not Linux-specific extensions. Still, you're right, so I safed it in a standard-compliant manner.

Comment: hi, Tomalak, thanks for your answer. I do not know why std:.string not used. Can you explain a bit more about the memory leak here? I do not quite get your point. How to avoid the memory leak here? Is it possible that I just do it by variable assignment, AString a; BString b; b.u1_list=a.val; b.i4_length=4096; as the solution post from marinara?

Comment: is copy needed for the cast? can anybody comment the solution from marinara? I am quite confused and do not know which is better.

Comment: @pepero: You have to copy the data from the source to the destination.

Comment: Hi, Tomalak, is it possible to use unsigned char p[N]; BString bs = { p, N }; then, std::copy(
      static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[0]),
      static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[N]),
      bs.u1_list
   ); to avoid using the heap memory allocation "new", which leads to memory leak?

Comment: @pepero: No, because the dimensions of an array must be known at compile-time; they cannot be variable like that.

Comment: @Tomalak, yes, you are right. Then what about this: unsigned char p[4096]; size_t const N = std::min(strlen(as.val), 4096); BString bs = { p, N }; then std::copy( static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[0]), static_cast<unsigned char*>(&as.val[N]), bs.u1_list ); Can this avoid using heap?

Comment: @pepero: No. You're assigning to the member inside `BString` a pointer to the automatic-storage array `p`, which will go out of scope and leave a dangling pointer. That was the problem with @marinara's answer.

Comment: hi, Tomalak, what if we do not make a separate function to do this, like the my "EDIT 1"? so the automatic-storage array p is at the same scope of result.

Comment: I also put EDIT_2. Welcome your comments, Tomalak.

Comment: @pepero: In both, you are correct; safe but awkward. The self-contained way to do this is to throw away this C nonsense and use an `std::vector`.

Comment: :-), absolutely agree with you!

Answer (score 4):

If it's about C, you should just implement 2 procedures like AStringToBString(struct AString* a, struct BString* b) and BStringToAString(struct BString* b, struct AString* a)

If it's about C++, you can implement the required wrappers for the places where you have to pass these strings. Make them just work with std::string. That's called Facade design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

```
int IamAwfulPureCProcedureThatDoesXXX(AString* a)
{
   ...
}
...
// what you do is:
int DoXXX(std::string const& a)
{
  AString aStr = MakeAStringFromStdString(a); // you have to implement it
  return IamAwfulPureCProcedureThatDoesXXX(aStr);
}
...
// then use as:
DoXXX("just a string");
```

Comment: +1 for std::string as an intermediary - it means writing 2 (or 4) conversions, but it also means you get to use normal C++ idioms in your code, and probably reduce the areas in the code where you need to worry about that memory-leak issue Tomalak mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

since nobody listed the simple answer, i will

```
#include <string.h>

void makeBString(AString &foo, BString& bar) {
bar.u1_list=foo.val;
bar.i4_length=strlen(foo.val);
}
```

Comment: oops forgot to cast BYTE* to char*

Comment: The pointer inside the `BString` will point to the array that's in the `AString`. Traditional ownership conventions dictate that each object "own" its own data. Here, as soon as your `AString` is destroyed, the pointer inside the `BString` is invalidated.

Comment: Also, `string.h` is deprecated, and who's talking about this imaginary `BYTE`?

Comment: as long as AString doesn't get deleted, BString fine.  If you're not sure how long AString instance lives, my code isn't a good idea.

Comment: Why complain about conventions? Conventions exist for a reason. Breaking them usually indicates poor, error-prone and/or broken code.

Comment: bet you didn't know that <cstring> #includes  <string.h>  OFC you didn't you're too busy being yourself

Comment: Yes, I know that (actually, the text of the standard says "as if", and makes no guarantees regarding implementation). Including `string.h` yourself is still deprecated. And please desist with the personal attacks; this is not the school playground.

Comment: HI, Tomalak and marinara, my case is that, I need to pass a variable of AString to a setter function with the parameter of BString pointer; like AString a; int funt(BString* b); I was quite wondering what i should do with the object ownership here. Personally, I think, sharing the object probably is good option here for me, as the variable is used just to set values. but i am not quite sure. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you do it my way, you won't lose any memory because BString never owns any memory.  anyhow all i got for this answer were downvotes.  probably my own fault....but

Comment: @marinara: Your way is highly susceptible to the dangling pointer problem. The "simple answer" actually makes things a lot more complicated, and thus your answer is dangerously misleading. That's why you have had nothing but downvotes.

Comment: @pepero: The answer to your question has been given; if you wish to discuss this sort of thing in a wider scope, I suggest hanging out in Stack Overflow chat. This Q&A post is starting to become rather iterative.

Comment: Tomalak, good point, indeed, i never use the StackOverflow chat feature. Anyway, thanks for the follow-up.